# How to configure gammu-smsd with mysql

Tags: mysql, gammu

I'm trying to start the gammu sms service, when I run it with simple archives, it runs fine, but when I try to run it with the mysql database, it shows this error:

## Error code: 2002, Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The restart gammu-sms, show this message:

```
user2@Lubuntu18:~$ service gammu-smsd restart
user2@Lubuntu18:~$ service gammu-smsd status
● gammu-smsd.service - SMS daemon for Gammu
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-08-18 20:55:21 -04; 2min 52s ago
     Docs: man:gammu-smsd(1)
  Process: 19001 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18999 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gammu-smsd --pid=/var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19000 (code=exited, status=2)

ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: Starting SMS daemon for Gammu...
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid (yet?) after start: No s
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: Started SMS daemon for Gammu.
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The log file gammu smsd show this:

```
Sat 2018/08/18 20:55:21 gammu-smsd[19000]: Error connecting to database!
Sat 2018/08/18 20:55:21 gammu-smsd[19000]: Error code: 2002, Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Sat 2018/08/18 20:55:21 gammu-smsd[19000]: Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Database connection timeout. (DB_TIMEOUT[78])
Sat 2018/08/18 20:55:21 gammu-smsd[19000]: Stopping Gammu smsd: Sin error. (NONE[1])
     Docs: man:gammu-smsd(1)
  Process: 19001 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18999 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gammu-smsd --pid=/var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19000 (code=exited, status=2)

ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: Starting SMS daemon for Gammu...
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid (yet?) after start: No s
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: Started SMS daemon for Gammu.
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
ago 18 20:55:21 Lubuntu18 systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The /etc/gammu-smsdrc is:

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = USB Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
connection = at
logfile = /home/ruser2/gammu.log
logformat = textall

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
runonreceive = /opt/lampp/htdocs/kalkun/scripts/daemon.sh
service = sql
Driver = native_mysql
PIN= 1234
logfile = /home/user2/gammusmsd.log
# Increase for debugging information
debuglevel = 0
user = kalkun
password = kalkun
pc = localhost
database = kalkun
```

---

I use Lubuntu:

18.04

xampp 5.6.30

PHP Version 5.6.23

---

Any idea to help me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user has no permission, you started as `user2@Lubuntu18`.

Try to start gammu-smsd as root, or add permission `dialout` to user2.

```
sudo gammu-smsd -d --user gammu --group dialout
```

Comment: Yes, I added my user to the group dialout and everything is ok. thanks