# How do i set up gammu-smsd.service on my RaspberryPi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, gammu

I'm trying to configure Gammu-smsd.services with mysql on my Rasberry Pi.
For information, gammu is working without smsd service.
smsd service is working when on defaut (not with mysql)

i got this kind of error :

```
pi@F1rst:/var/log $ sudo systemctl status gammu-smsd.service
● gammu-smsd.service - SMS daemon for Gammu
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-01-14 18:16:26 CET; 24min ago
     Docs: man:gammu-smsd(1)
  Process: 4318 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4312 ExecStart=/usr/bin/gammu-smsd --pid=/var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4313 (code=exited, status=2)

janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst systemd[1]: Starting SMS daemon for Gammu...
janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst gammu-smsd[4312]: Log filename is "/var/log/smsd"
janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst systemd[1]: Started SMS daemon for Gammu.
janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit entered failed state.
janv. 14 18:16:26 F1rst systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And the smsd log give me this :

```
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4312]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4313]: Connected to Database: smsd on localhost
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4313]: Failed to seek to first row!
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4313]: Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Erreur inconnue. (UNKNOWN[27])
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4313]: Stopping Gammu smsd: Aucune erreur. (NONE[1])
```

Here is my gammu-smsdrc configuration file :

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
# Please configure this!
port = /dev/ttyAMA0
connection = at115200

# Debugging
#logformat = textall

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
#RunOnReceive = /home/pi/script/sms.sh
service = sql
driver = native_mysql
host = localhost
user = smsd
password = g@mmuP@ssword
database = smsd
logfile = /var/log/smsd
# Increase for debugging information
debuglevel = 0

# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

I tried the solution [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914008/how-to-configure-gammu-smsd-with-mysql) but it didnt work.

Do someone got an idea for me ?

Thanks by advance for you time.
Maybe it's a very easy fix but i'm a real beginner

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figure it out.

The probleme where there :

```
Mon 2019/01/14 18:16:26 gammu-smsd[4313]: Failed to seek to first row!
```

I found [this video](https://youtu.be/ZHzUKFiCEeE) witch tell you to do this :
Entrer your smsd database using phpmyadmin
Seek for the gammu Table and insert the value "13"

I tryed then it din't worked but the error did change.
I had at this moment this error :

```
Sat 2019/01/19 13:12:21 gammu-smsd[30893]: Database structure is from older Gammu version
```

So i change the value to 20
Then i got this :

```
Sat 2019/01/19 13:08:31 gammu-smsd[30705]: Database structure is from newer Gammu version
```

After few time i entrer the value '16' and it worked !!!